# Printing s3 bucket upload object key with lambda with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

The following is a test example supplied by aws lambda for s3 events:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test/key",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am specifically wondering, how would i print the `object: key:`?

Specifically`"test/key"` ?

I have tried this and a few other ways to no success:

```
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-elastictranscoder'
require "aws-sdk-s3"

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    src_bkt = "example-bucket"
    src_key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key

    s3.getObject({
        Bucket: src_bkt,
        Key: src_key
    })
    # TODO implement
    { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate(src_key) }
end
```

The response i get with this is a failed response with the following:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "undefined method `Records' for #<Hash:0x0000561d9afa6618>",
  "errorType": "Function<NoMethodError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:7:in `lambda_handler'"
  ]
}
```

Update:

I am able to print the entire Record with:

```
def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    body = JSON.generate(event)
    parse = JSON.parse(body)

    puts(parse["Records"])
end
```

But one i add to the puts/print something like:

`puts(parse["Records"]["object"]["key"])`

I get errors such as:

`"errorMessage": "no implicit conversion of String into Integer",`

Comment: Why are you accessing the hash values as if they were methods on the object? is something additional you're using for that?

Comment: I'm trying to define `"object": {
          "key": "test/key",` so i can use that name to create a watermark on a file upload.  I have successfully used lambda to do this, but i can't figure out how to identify the file that is creating the trigger from the s3 upload.  I need to define a file in the s3 bucket in order for a watermark to be created on the file.  so with this i am testing how to identify the key so i can use that as the file name

Comment: Due to the way your data is represented, isn't it `parse[:Records][0][:s3][:object][:key]` (or `parse['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])`?

Comment: I actually got that working a short time ago with the exact code, just with double quotations.  but now the lambda loops.  so now i need to figure that out

Answer (score 1):

What if you do the following:

```
record = event["Records"][0]
key = record.dig *%w(s3 object key)
```

The reason you are confused, I think, is because the `event` object is a hash with a key `Records` that contains an array of all of the event records. So instead of converting to JSON, you could pull the record out instead (first line) and then access the key with the `dig` method of the Hash (I find it really convenient when traversing AWS event record hashes).

Comment: So this works and is less code from what i had.  Now my issue is the lambda continuously loops due to the same file uploading and triggering the lambda over and over.  What do you think is a good way to break the loop.......Now, the only bad thing is I'm using Active Storage so the bucket needs to stay the same.

Comment: @uno are you trying to trigger the lambda only when it initially uploads, and not every time it has been updated?

Comment: It works on PUT, when i change to POST, nothing happens.   So a user uploads a video, the video watermark is applied, it loops... it would like for it to stop once the watermark is applied.  I figured doing POST would solve the issue but it won't even trigger unless on PUT?

Comment: @uno According to the docs, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types, the different PUT and POST event types are from the different API's available to access S3 objects. If you are having trouble because you are rewriting the same file, what if you try versioning items and only processing the request if the file has a certain version?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? Are you saying, only allow eg: .mov file and then output the file in .mp4? so then it won't loop?

Comment: @uno s3 buckets can be configured to be versioned, so every time you change the object, it's given a new version. That way if the object is updated, you will be able to detect that the version is different and the lambda can shortcirtuit, preventing an infinite loop